# SimpleImputer Using both columns to calculate average

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using SimpleImputer and most_frequent to calculate the missing values in my dataset. Problem is that the two columns aren't being treated independently, therefore I am getting the most common value in the first column being used to replace NaN in the second column, which obviously skews my data.

code below

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent',)
imputer.fit(X[:, 2:4])
X[:, 2:4] = imputer.transform(X[:, 2:4])

print(X[:, 3])

[2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1517.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1517.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 1517.0 2.0 1517.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1517.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2426.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1517.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0]
```

Comment: So you want to fit and transform each column independently right?

Comment: Yes, I though that’s what SimpleImputer did?

Comment: Not if you pass the full matrix (df). If you want to go on a column-by-column case, you'd need to loop, or use `.apply()` let me work a quick example so I can post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying many different methods using dict comprehension and `apply` but I can't seem to get it to work in a single line of code. Therefore I can only think of using a for loop to iterate over the columns you want to use the `SimpleImputer` on and apply it:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,4,8],
                  'B':[2,2,2,2,2,2,np.nan],
                  'C':[6,5,np.nan,6,4,4,6],
                  'D':[1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,3,4]})
cols = X.columns[2:]
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
for i in cols:
  X[i] = imputer.fit_transform(X[i].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Which fills the 3rd and 4th columns, but not the second one (that's why the `NaN` in the second column. Also you can see that regardless of `2` being the most frequent number in the dataframe, the columns get filled with the most frequent number in the respective column:

```
   A    B    C    D
0  1  2.0  6.0  1.0
1  2  2.0  5.0  2.0
2  3  2.0  6.0  3.0
3  4  2.0  6.0  3.0
4  5  2.0  4.0  3.0
5  4  2.0  4.0  3.0
6  8  NaN  6.0  4.0
```

I will do further investigation to try and apply this without needing a for loop, and update this answer. For the time being, this seems to do the job.